# Store repeat DataTables data in select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, dynamic, datatables

I need an elegant way to store repeat data in select dropdowns within DataTables. For example, I have 2 questions and each question can have various answers. In this instance, question 1 (keyno 1) has 2 possible answers and question 2 (keyno 2) has 3 possible answers. In the fiddle example, there are 5 rows (which holds repeat information) yet there should only be 2 (one for each keyno). How can I dynamically create dropdowns holding the answers and only show my 2 rows, like a for loop? I'm not certain.

http://jsfiddle.net/s827x/28/

```
var data = [
        {'keyno': '1', 'quest': 'Does a cat meow?', 'ans': 'yes'},
        {'keyno': '1', 'quest': 'Does a cat meow?', 'ans': 'no'},
        {'keyno': '2', 'quest': 'What color is a stop sign?', 'ans': 'red'},
        {'keyno': '2', 'quest': 'What color is a stop sign?', 'ans': 'yellow'},
        {'keyno': '2', 'quest': 'What color is a stop sign?', 'ans': 'green'}
    ]

    $('#questtable').DataTable({
            "data": data,
            "columns": [
                { data: 'keyno' },
                { data: 'quest' },
                { data: 'ans' }
            ]
    });
```

Comment: you need to reduce that down to two rows, each with an array for ans instead of a string. i like to use mustache to turn the dumb json from my server into dumb html that datatable injects into the cell, so i don't have to build HTML using JS.

Comment: i don't know how to create a new array from my existing array in this instance.

Comment: well that is what you need to do, but i admit it's not easy. something like lodash could help, but it will still require a bit of legwork. might be better to repose the question about transforming the "json". at any rate, once the row quest doesn't repeat and ans contains all possibilities instead, turning a col into a dropdown is pretty simple, and you're on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was having an array for my questions and array for answers, with keynos that later match up. The table loads the questions, and on redraw adds the dropdown options after clearing a loop to match answers to questions. :D http://jsfiddle.net/s827x/37/

```
$('#questtable').DataTable({
        "data": quest,
        "columns": [
            { data: 'keyno' },
            { data: 'quest' },
            {
                data: 'ans',
                "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                    return '<select id="'+full.keyno+'"></select>';
                }
            }
        ],
        "fnDrawCallback": function () {
            $('#questtable tbody tr').each(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
                    if ($(this).find('td').eq(0).text() == ans[i].keyno) {
                        $(this).find('td').eq(2).find('select').append('<option value="' + ans[i].ans + '">' + ans[i].ans+ '</option>');

                    }
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
```